# FullCalendar - removeEventSources : modify , add or delete individual source arrays

Tags: fullcalendar

I want to be able to modify , or add or delete individual source arrays in the eventSources array. But I am not sure how to remove individual event sources. Because they get merged together - how would I remove individual ones?

I add them in this way:

```
 eventSources: [
    eventSource1,
    holidays,
    flagDays,
    churchDays
 ]
```

They get merged as one array. So I can't get the first array (eventSource1) by doing:

```
var currentEvents = $('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents'); 
var eventSource1 = currentEvents[0];       //<-- undefined
```

I tried adding them wrapped in separate arrays:

```
eventSources: [
        [eventSource1],
        [holidays],
        [flagDays],
        [churchDays]
     ]
```

But now they are not loaded into the calendar,the calendar is empty.

In the documentation: [removeEventSources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/removeEventSources) it says you are supposed to provide an "optionalSourcesArray" which should contain

> "identifier items, which can be either an event source’s
>   id/Array/URL/Function or the full Event Source Object.".

I can't guess what they mean by it. I use version 3.9.

--------------**Update**:-----------------

Using below comment I can do:

```
eventSources: [
                { id: 1,
                    events: eventSource1
                },
                { id: 2,
                    events: holidays
                },
                { id: 3,
                    events: flagDays
                },
                { id: 4,
                    events: churchDays
                }  
    ]
```

Then I can delete individual event sources - if I want to delete the first three:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSources', [1,2,3] ) ;
```

The final thing I need is to be able to get an event source array.
I can use the `getEventSourceById` method:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'getEventSourceById', 4 );
```

But this gives me a class object - how will I get the event source array?

Comment: It means, for example, that if you defined your event source as an object as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object, and give it an "id" property, then you can use that id to reference it when you want to delete it. Or, if you defined your event source as a URL (i.e. to point fullCalendar to where it can download the events from), then it assumes that URL will be unique (since you wouldn't download the same stuff twice) and therefore you could use that to identify it.

Comment: Or if you passed in your event source as an array, you could give a reference to the same array when deleting and it would match it to the one passed in originally. Same if you declared the event source as a function, passing a reference to the same function would work. Does that help?

Comment: When I try to put the sources into an object instead:  {
        1: eventSource1,
        2: holidays,
        3: flagDays,
        4: churchDays
     }       , I get the error   "n.forEach is not a function" and the calendar doesn't load.

Comment: If I kept them as an array, It didn't work when trying to reference their array indexes like : $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSources',0 )  OR $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSources', [1,2,3]) .  I need an explicit example.

Comment: "When I try to put the sources in an object instead"... that's not what I said or what I meant. `eventSources` must still be an array, but it may be an an array _containing_ (1 or more) objects, each of which represents a separate source. Those objects can have properties matching the ones described in https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-source-object

Comment: If you're using static arrays, then each object could be of the form `{ id: 1
  events: [
    {
      title: 'Event1',
      start: '2011-04-04'
    },
    {
      title: 'Event2',
      start: '2011-05-05'
    }
    // etc...
  ]` similar to what's described in that link. So your object consists of two properties: "events" containing your event data, and "id", which we'll use to identify it when we remove the source. You should then be able to call `.fullCalendar( 'removeEventSource', 1 )` to remove the source whose ID is 1.

Comment: Note that the ID is not at all the same as the array index, which you were trying to use. The documentation doesn't mention that you can use those.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I can remove individual event sources. I wasn't successful in getting an event source however. If use the 'getEventSourceById' method like: $('#calendar').fullCalendar( 'getEventSourceById', 4 ) , I get a class object in return, but I wanted the array of events(!?). Any clues on that?

Comment: I would expect the events are in a property inside that object. Probably the "events" property, assuming it matches the structure of the event source object you input (as per my example). I would expect it returns the same structure back again Did you log the object to the console so you could see its structure and work out where the events might be within it? That would have been the first thing to try, really.

Comment: Yes, I had overlooked something...  I had found "eventDefs" property which had all the events as class objects, and I wanted the original array... But just now I found "rawEventDefs" - that's the array I want : )    So, that's all I need - thanks for helping.